# How can I make this F# function tail-recursive in all cases?

Tags: recursion, f#

I have been working my way through this year's Advent of Code problems in F# as a means of improving my skills in this language. I have come up with the following solution for [Day 8, Part 1](https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/8):

```
namespace AdventOfCode2018.Core

module Day8 =

    let calculatePart1 input = 
        let rec take numberToTake numberTaken taken remaining =
            if numberTaken = numberToTake || List.isEmpty remaining then
                taken, remaining
            else
                take numberToTake (numberTaken + 1) 
                    (List.head remaining :: taken) (List.tail remaining)

        let rec calculate input sum depth maxDepth =
            let quantityOfChildNodes, quantityOfMetadata, remaining = 
                match input with
                | qc :: qm :: tl -> qc, qm, tl
                | _ -> 0, 0, []
            let input, sum = 
                match quantityOfChildNodes with 
                | 0 -> remaining, sum
                | q -> calculate remaining sum 1 q
            let metadata, remaining = take quantityOfMetadata 0 [] input
            let sum = sum + List.sum metadata
            if depth = maxDepth then remaining, sum
            else calculate remaining sum (depth + 1) maxDepth

        calculate input 0 0 1 |> snd
```

My code produces the correct solution to the problem and seems to run quickly enough (13ms using my puzzle input on an i7 machine). However, when debugging the code I noticed that it was not tail-recursive. The first recursive call within `calculate` generates a new stack frame.  The second recursive call at the end of the function doesn't.  I'm sure it must be possible to write the first call to be tail-recursive, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: If you need two recursive calls to compute your return value, there is no way to avoid memory allocation: you have to remember the result of the first call somewhere while you're performing the second call. In your case you remember it on the stack. It is possible to make it technically tail-recursive via continuation passing, but that will just shift memory allocation to the heap. There is no way to achieve constant space, unless you can reformulate your algorithm to be linear.

Comment: I agree with Fyodor that constant space seems out of reach but you could rewrite the algorithm to use a list to build up the state. That way the main loop could be tail-recursive and the list is not limited by available stack space but rather heap space.